# Adding variables to database with a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, loops

My main question is why is PDO::exec not executing every iteration of my loop, and instead only executing in the first iteration.

I am trying to insert coordinates into my MySQL database.

My database structure is (number(primary key), x, y, z).

I ask the user to insert a number ($n), and then ask them to fill in $n sets of coordinates.

The users inputs are passed to another page with $_POST, then retrieved by dynamic variable names and inserted into the database.

Everything works, except the loop only writes to the database its first iteration. So I end up with results for x1,z1,y1 but nothing else.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong (other than not using arrays)?

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
$n = $_POST['selectOption'];

for($i = 1; $i < $n+1;$i++){
    ${'x' . $i} = $_POST["x" . $i];
    ${'y' . $i} = $_POST["y" . $i];
    ${'z' . $i} = $_POST["z" . $i];

    $rowsAffected = $db->exec("INSERT INTO coordinate3d (number,x,y,z)
              VALUES ('$n', '${'x' . $i}', '${'y' . $i}', '${'z' . $i}')");
}
?>
```

Here is my form

```
<form action="aaron_stockdale_dynamic_process.php" method="post" name="coordinateForm">
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
            {
        ?>
          x<?php echo $i+1;?> <input name="x<?php echo $i+1;?>" type=text>, y<?php echo $i+1;?> <input name="y<?php echo $i+1;?>" type=text>, z<?php echo $i+1;?> <input name="z<?php echo $i+1;?>" type=text><br>

    <?php 
        }
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="selectOption" value="<?php echo $n;?>">
    <input type="submit" oonClick="document.location.href='aaron_stockdale_dynamic_process.php'" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why not just give them unique names? `$x,$y,$z`

Comment: And this is wrong syntax `$ < $n+1` do `$i < $n+1`

Comment: Did that code work at all?  wrong:`$n = $_POST('numberOfCoordinates');`, right: `$n = $_POST['numberOfCoordinates'];`

Comment: Would it not be more logical if the following was changed `${'x' . $i} = $_POST["x" . $i];` to `$x = $_POST["x" . $i];`.... also you may want to look into sanitation.

Comment: You always while developing `error_reporting(E_ALL)`!

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I corrected the () to [] for $_POST . It was a typo but not actually in my code.

Comment: @sircrisp there are so many errors in the code you provided, will you please look through it and correct the things... would you release a book without proof reading it, wtf?

Comment: @Hallur all is corrected.

Comment: Can you post the code for the form too?

Comment: Also `'$n'` in the SQL inserts always the SAME number, use `$i` there.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions that is intended.

Comment: @Hallur form added

Comment: Last note here: Try to create an SQL like `INSERT INTO coordinate3d (number,x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,4)` and insert all data at once ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 require_once('aaron_stockdale_database.php');
 $n = $_POST['selectOption'];

for($i = 1; $i < $n+1;$i++){
  $x = $_POST["x" . $i];
  $y = $_POST["y" . $i];
  $z = $_POST["z" . $i];

$rowsAffected = $db->exec("INSERT INTO coordinate3d (number,x,y,z)
          VALUES ('$n', '$x', '$y', '$z')");
}
```

the rest is on you ;)

And also check if any of the fields a primary key, that will prevent insert it twice.

Comment: This just overwrites my variables, I need to use them outside of the loop so it will not work.

Comment: Did you know `extract($_POST)`?? and/or: you have $_POST after the loop anyway!

Comment: My main question is why PDO::exec is not executing more than once despite being in a loop.  Even after changing my code to reflect yours it still only writes the first iteration of the loop to the database.

Comment: @sircrisp since nobody knows `aaron_stockdale_database.php` here, what can we say? Or maybe db.table field `number` is primary key! Is `$n` greater tha `0`? Thing you should reopen tha question with working code and more detaild information. You also dont have posted (or used?) mysql loggings...

Comment: You were right about the issue being number being the primary key, submit it as an answer and I will be happy to credit you after I include the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have received an acceptable answer for your question, I'd like to give you a hint on your html code.

```
<form action="aaron_stockdale_dynamic_process.php" method="post" name="coordinateForm">
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
?>
x<?php echo $i+1;?> <input name="x<?php echo $i+1;?>" type=text>, y<?php echo $i+1;?> <input name="y<?php echo $i+1;?>" type=text>, z<?php echo $i+1;?> <input name="z<?php echo $i+1;?>" type=text><br>

<?php 
}
?>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="selectOption" value="<?php echo $n;?>">
<input type="submit" oonClick="document.location.href='aaron_stockdale_dynamic_process.php'" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, this code can be cleaned up a bit.

```
<form action="aaron_stockdale_dynamic_process.php" method="post" name="coordinateForm">
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
echo 'x' . $i+1 . '<input name="x' . $i+1 . '" type=text>, y' . $i+1 . ' <input name="y' . $i+1. '" type=text>, z' . $i+1 . '<input name="z' . $i+1 . '" type=text><br>'
}
?>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="selectOption" value="<?php echo $n;?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I changed the "oonClick" to "onClick", and then afterwards I removed it, as when you submit, you don't need to navigate, as the browser will do this, upon submission. 
And then I removed the repetitive opening and closing of php tags, and combined all the echos into one.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution in one file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <script>
      function validcoord(e) {
        var key;
        var keychar;

        if (window.event)
          key = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e)
          key = e.which;
        else
          return true;
        keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
        keychar = keychar.toLowerCase();

        // control keys
        if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
          return true;

        // Numeral Characters
        else if ((("0123456789-.,").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      input[type="number"] { text-align: right; width: 50px; }
      label { margin-left: 4em; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      define ("SELF", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
      define ("EOL", "\r\n");
      // Modify as needed
      define ("MINNUMCORDS" ,  "1");
      define ("MAXNUMCORDS" , "10");
      define ("DFLTNUMCORDS",  "2");

      $formSubmitted = (empty($_POST)) ? FALSE : TRUE;

      if (!$formSubmitted) {
        $htmlOutput = '
          <form action="' . SELF . '" method=post name=foo id=foo>
            <input type=hidden name=current value=0>
            <label>Enter the number of Coordinates:
            <input type=number autofocus onFocus="this.select()"' .
                  ' min=' . MINNUMCORDS . 
                  ' max=' . MAXNUMCORDS . 
                ' value=' . DFLTNUMCORDS .
                 ' name=numcords /></label>
          </form>' . EOL;
          echo $htmlOutput;
      } // end if not submitted
      else { // a form HAS been submitted

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $$key = $value; }
        unset($_POST);

        if (!empty($coord)) { // We got some input that may be a valid x,y,z coordinate
          if ( substr_count($coord, ",") != 2 ) {
            $error = "We're looking for THREE numbers seperated by TWO commas.";
          } // end  if we don't have three values
          else { // We got three Values
            $coord = trim($coord);
            list($x,$y,$z) = explode(",", $coord);
            if ( !(is_numeric($x) && is_numeric($y) && is_numeric($z)) ) {
              $error = "We're looking for three VALID NUMBERS seperated by two commas.";
            } // end if all three numbers are not valid
            else { // We got three Values and each of them are numbers
              require('db.php');
              $rowsAffected = $db->exec("INSERT INTO coordinate3d (number,x,y,z)
                  VALUES ('$numcords', '$x', '$y', '$z')"); 
              //echo "INSERT INTO coordinate3d (number,x,y,z) VALUES ('$numcords', '$x', '$y', '$z')<br />" . EOL;
            } // end three valid numbers
          } // end three values
        } // end if we have some input in $coord

        if ($error) {
          echo "~~ " . $error . "<br /><br />" . EOL;
          --$current;
        } // end if error

        if ( $current < $numcords ) {
          $htmlOutput  = 'Please enter the coordinate in the form: x,y,z (Ex: -.4,2,8.5)' . EOL;
          $htmlOutput .= '<form action="' . SELF . '" method=post name=bar id=bar>' . EOL;
          $htmlOutput .= '  <input type=hidden name=numcords value="' . $numcords . '" />' . EOL;
          $htmlOutput .= '  <input type=hidden name=current value="' . ++$current . '" />' . EOL;
          $htmlOutput .= '  <label>Coord #' . $current . ': ';
          $htmlOutput .=   '<input type=text name=coord size=12 maxlength=48 ' .
                              'autofocus onKeyPress="return validcoord(event);" /></label>' . EOL;
          $htmlOutput .= '</form>' . EOL;
          echo $htmlOutput;
        } // end if we need to get another coord
      } // end form was submitted
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```